# React Typescript error with valid property

Tags: reactjs, typescript, runtime-error, syntax-error

I'm looking to create a component that will accept one of two possible configurations (see code).

Within the defined type, `foo2` should be valid but the error states:

> Property 'foo2' does not exist on type '{ foo: string; bar: string; } | { foo2: number; }'.
> Property 'foo2' does not exist on type '{ foo: string; bar: string; }'.ts(2339)

I want to be able to require either `foo` + `bar` or just `foo2` which does work but I am unable to do extra logical checks due to the error. What is the solution for this scenario?

```js
type MyComponentProps = {
  config:
    | {
        foo: string;
        bar: string;
      }
    | {
        foo2: number;
      };
};

function MyComponent({config}: MyComponentProps) {
  if (config?.foo2) {
    //do something
  }

  return null;
}
```

[image: error]

Comment: @TobiasS. Yes, that question has details that relate to my question.

Answer (score 1):

foo2 doesn't exist on the first type in the union so you need to check for it:

```
  if ('foo2' in config) {
    // foo2 is now available
    config.foo2
  }
```